# unmarshal xml element defined in external xsd using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, any

I would like to unmarshal an XML file with this xsd [definition](http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd) using jaxb.

I have generated java classes using eclipse right click, generate jaxb classes, etc. I have no problems unmarshalling XML files.

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how  to un marshal (map?) MetadataType. Below is the xsd definition for metadataType and the class generated:

```
<complexType name="metadataType">
    <annotation>
      <documentation>Metadata must be expressed in XML that complies
       with another XML Schema (namespace=#other). Metadata must be 
       explicitly qualified in the response.</documentation>
    </annotation>
    <sequence>
      <any namespace="##other" processContents="strict"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
```

Generated class for this Type is:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2012.11.08 at 05:28:26 PM PST 
//


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * Metadata must be expressed in XML that complies
 *        with another XML Schema (namespace=#other). Metadata must be 
 *        explicitly qualified in the response.
 * 
 * <p>Java class for metadataType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="metadataType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;any namespace='##other'/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "metadataType", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class MetadataType {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected Object any;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public Object getAny() {
        return any;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the any property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public void setAny(Object value) {
        this.any = value;
    }

}
```

The external xsd for  is [here](http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd)

The unmarshalled XML doc generate this:
[image: unmarshalled XML data]

UPDATE:

Also, I've generated classes from the external [xsd](http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd):

OaiDcType.java
ElementType.java

Those classes must contain the data of MetadataType object.

I would like to convert **any** to my own OaiDcType object, wich is the correct/best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM `Element` is what you get from an `any` when the `JAXBContext` doesn't know anything about the type of the element it found in the XML. If you have JAXB annotated classes for the element in question and the `JAXBContext` knows about these as well as the top level OAI-PMH classes then the element will automatically get unmarshalled to the relevant class and `getAny` will return that object rather than an Element.

Comment: Fist you must add to ObjectFactory.java OaiDcType and ElementType classes, so those will be in the JAXBContext. Then,   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("<path.to.your.package>");
     Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
     JAXBElement<OAIPMHtype> root = u.unmarshal(records.getDocument(),
       OAIPMHtype.class);
     OAIPMHtype response = root.getValue();
     MetadataType metadata = response.getListRecords().getRecord().get(<some_integer>).getMetadata();
     JAXBElement<OaiDcType> element = (JAXBElement<OaiDcType>)metadata.getAny();

Answer (score 1):

If you also have JAXB classes generated for the oai_dc.xsd schema, you should be able to just perform another unmarshal:

```
MetadataType metadata = ...;
Node oaidcNode = (Node)metadata.getAny(); // org.w3c.dom.Node
JAXBContext oaidcContext = ...;
Unmarshaller oaidcUnmarshaller = oaidcContext.createUnmarshaller();
// use Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Node) or Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Node, Class<T>)
```

Comment: Or even better, if you include these oai_dc classes along with the OAI-PMH ones in the original `JAXBContext` that you used to unmarshal the top-level response then you will get the unmarshalled object directly from `getAny()` instead of getting DOM elements.

Comment: @Ian...no idea why I didn't go there, but if that works and it's down to just a cast, then that *is* better. Think about pulling your comment out into an answer - I'm happy to drop mine if yours works...

Comment: @IanRoberts, your solution works for me, and I think it is the best/correct way to do that. From: fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/jaxws/JAXWSAnyElementMapping.html. With @XmlAnyElement(lax = true) you are telling the runtime to check for the right classes to unmarshal in.